# Primer on Random Forest Algorithm

Tags: random-forest

I wanted to ensure that I understood the random forest algorithm right. I think it's fundamental to understand how something work before using it!

Am I right with this:[image: Random Forest Algorithm]

If not: what did I understand wrong?

Comment: I took a quick look and the picture looks okay to me. You calculate the importance score with the OOB data set. Best for you to read a text book.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I think I got it now. It should be like this:

[image: RandomForest2]

Am I right? If not: whats wrong?